# "My Location" history in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've enabled "My Location" in Google Maps. Is there a simple way to get data showing where I've been? If not, how might I go about collecting this data in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "My Location" map at: http://google.com/locationhistory

Comment: Hey's thats a great page! I was trying to make something like that when I asked this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a smartphone, you could install Google Latitude. I think it works with laptops using the w3c geolocation service, too. https://www.google.com/latitude/ I doubt you can just see your google maps history -- you might actually have to visit Google Latitude to add a data point.

Comment: Yeah I was doubting that myself. I'll see where I can get with Latitude.

Answer (score 1):

As theazureshadow mentioned, Google Latitude can be used to track your location. There is a dashboard where you can see maps of your location history, Google Latitude also has an API: http://www.google.com/intl/en/latitude/api.html